# worklight 6.0.0 facebook app fails to call a worklight adapter

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

we are doing worklight app on a android and a desktopenvironment(for facebook) that works fine on the liberty profile server (developer worklight environment).
Know we need to post this app on Facebook but to do this we need to use the https protocol on our WAS server, to do this we set the ip, port, protocol: to our external server, and deploy our app with build for remote server, but when the app tried to call an adapter on the server, the Firefox console returns us this:

```
[09:58:50.675] "response [https://[publicIP]:[port]/WorklightPocProj/apps/services/../../invoke] success: /*-secure-
{"challenges":{"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"WL-Instance-Id":"ih80d8pjg6la8ubccb7503b936"}}}*/"
```

and

```
[09:58:50.675] "defaultOptions:onFailure Procedure invocation error."
```

The application security on our WAS server is disabled and the ip/port are reachable too.
if i add to the XML adapter on the procedures securityTest="wl_unprotected" the app runs correctly, but i don't to do this workaround

Is there any configuration that we are missing on the app or in our WAS server?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of time since this question but just for trying to help people that hit this question because of the search "defaultOptions:onFailure Procedure invocation error".

Also facing this issue in Worklight 6.1

In my case I faced this issue because I had the following configuration in the adapter .xml:

```
<procedure name="anyMethod"></procedure>
```

This works in the development server, but in a stand alone server (at least in WAS) you have to change it for:

```
<procedure name="submitAuthentication" securityTest="wl_unprotected"></procedure>
```

In both cases it is unprotected.

Comment: but the user wrote he does not want it to be unprotected; also, there is no "have to" here... the problem is elsewhere.